# Problem: failed to create task or type projectImport

Tags: eclipse, ant

I'm quite new with ANT to build an Eclipse (Oxygen) project. I'm using existing build.xml file which previously written in RAD environment.

Here is my build.xml task;

```
<foreach
 list="${projects.name}"
 param="project"
 target="import-project" /> 

<target name="import-project">
    <!-- Debug information -->
    <echo message="project.name=${project}" />
    <echo message="projectLocation=${rad.workspace}\${project}" />

    <projectImport
        projectName="${project}"
        projectLocation="${rad.workspace}\${project}" /> 

    <echo message="projectImport ${project} done" /> 
</target>
```

And here is the error

```
BUILD FAILED
Problem: failed to create task or type projectImport
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

I don't know whether `projectImport` is available in Eclipse or only in IBM RAD. But if the task is available in Eclipse, do you have any idea why task is failed and if the task only available in IBM RAD, what are the tasks available for me to import project to current workspace.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`projectImport` is IBM RAD only. I don't know of any standard Eclipse equivalent.

Standard Eclipse only provides a very small number of Ant tasks and they all start with `eclipse.`. See [here](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fant_eclipse_tasks.htm) for the Eclipse tasks list.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449, and I think I've already solved the problem by using <copy> task.

Comment: Although copy can put things in the workspace directory I don't think Eclipse will recognise the new projects automatically.